# Print data recieved by node.js server to console

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I have a java class sending data to a node.js server...

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class TestingServer
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
    try
        {
            String testData = " Test data...";
            Socket nodejs = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
            Thread.sleep(100);
            for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                //Thread.sleep(400);
                sendMessage(nodejs, i + testData + " ");
                System.out.println(i + "  <----Message sent to server");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println("Server closed...oops");
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void sendMessage(Socket s, String message) throws IOException
        {
            s.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            s.getOutputStream().flush();
        }

    }
```

Node.js...

```
var javaPort = 8080;
var javaServer = require('net').createServer();
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server , javaSocket = new WebSocketServer({port: 90});

var fileData ;

console.log('====================================================');
console.log('Node.js/Java Communication Module');
console.log('====================================================');

javaServer.on('listening', function(){console.log('Server is listening on ' + javaPort);});

javaServer.on('error', function(e){console.log('Server error: ' + e.code);});

javaServer.on('close', function(){console.log('Server closed');});

javaServer.on('connection', function(javaSocket){
    var clientAddress = javaSocket.address().address+':'+javaSocket.address().port;
    console.log('Java ' + clientAddress + ' connected');});

var firstDataListener = function(data){
  fileData = data;
  console.log('Data recieved from java: ' + fileData);
}

javaSocket.on('data', firstDataListener);

javaSocket.on('close', function(){
console.log('Java ' + clientAddress + ' disconnected');
});

javaServer.listen(javaPort);
```

It successfully listens, and connects,

How do i print the data sent to the server on the server side console?

I was told theres too much code and not enough detail to post so this is me just saying stuff to allow me to post, because thats all the information i have.

Comment: javaServer.on('listening',...) and javaServer.on('connection',...)

Comment: the 'listening' and 'connection' events are emitted

Comment: **What** messages are you getting on the server and client consoles?

Comment: on server        |====================================================                             Node.js/Java Communication Module ====================================================                     Server is listening on 8080                                             Java localhost:8080|                                                 On client                                                            |Test data... <----Message sent to server                            is printed 99 times.| Also I dont know how to make this format nicely in a comment. Used bars to seperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're listening for 'data' on the server itself instead of each incoming connection. You want this instead:

```
// ...

javaServer.on('connection', function(javaSocket){
  var clientAddress = javaSocket.address().address+':'+javaSocket.address().port;
  console.log('Java ' + clientAddress + ' connected');
  javaSocket.on('data', function(data){
    fileData = data;
    console.log('Data recieved from java: ' + fileData);
  }).on('close', function() {
    console.log('Java ' + clientAddress + ' disconnected');
  });
});

javaServer.listen(javaPort);
```